Find the number of distinct cubes that can be made by painting each face of a given cube in one of the 5 given colors
Not all of the colors have to be used and cubes are distinct if they cannot be obtained from each other using rotations.
Classic combinatorics question, the answer I have requires burnside's lemma but is there an easier way?
I thought it was just 5^6 for the total amount of arrangement of colours and divide it by 24 which are total ways to rotate the cube, but it is not even an integer, what have I done wrong?

This is the point of Burnside. While most painting patterns can be rotated 24 ways and give 24 different views, some patterns are symmetric in some way and give fewer than 24 different views. So by simply dividing by 24 you are wrongly assuming there are no symmetric patterns resulting in a non-integer that is smaller than the real answer.
For example, if only one colour is used, the cube looks the same however you rotate it, so this pattern has only one view instead of 24. There are five of these patterns (because there are 5 colours).
There are patterns with other kinds of symmetry, and Burnside takes care of all that. It does this essentially by adding all those symmetric rotations to fix it so that you can actually divide by 24.
I don't think there is any other way to calculate this that is easier than Burnside's Lemma. If you try to classify all the types of symmetry a pattern can have and then count how many there are of each, you can get bogged down in an inclusion-exclusion problem. Burnside groups the various patterns based on which symmetries they share, allowing them to be counted relatively easily.

Thanks mate I'll look into burnside then
